# Importar módulo após função .load() do jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, módulo-ecmascript

Porque não é possível importar um módulo depois do carregamento de um conteúdo externo pelo jQuery[.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/), pelo o que entendi ele precisa estar fora do escopo, mas fora do escopo o conteúdo do script não é lido, resultando na mensagem de erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level
> of a module

O módulo já foi carregado na página e funciona nas chamadas dos botões existentes, mas não é reconhecido no conteúdo criado na DOM, então pensei que assim fosse possível, mas não.

Talvez existe um outro modo de linkar a função ao conteúdo externo carregado, mas o que tentei foi abaixo, resultando no erro.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','button.btn-load-items',function( event ) {          
        event.preventDefault();
        let token = $(this).data('category');
        $( 'div#load' + token ).load( 'load-items.php?token=' + token, function (e) {
            $( 'div.load-images' + token ).hide();
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('div#load'+token).offset().top - 50 }, 500, function() {
                
                $.getScript("assets/js/velocity.min.js", function() {
                    console.log('ok');
                });
                
                /* ---------------------- AQUI -------------------------- */
                import QuantityInput from './assets/vendors/quantity-button/quantity.js';

                (function(){
                    let quantities = document.querySelectorAll('[data-quantity]');
                    if (quantities instanceof Node) quantities = [quantities];
                    if (quantities instanceof NodeList) quantities = [].slice.call(quantities);
                    if (quantities instanceof Array) {
                        quantities.forEach(div => (div.quantity = new QuantityInput(div, 'Down', 'Up')));
                    }
                })();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, fiz um exemplo rápido para você utilizar...

Pelo que vi rápido em seu script, não segue os padrões do `import`, pelo que sei da forma que utilizou deve ser iniciado o script e não colocar no corpo de um script js, passei por isso no inicio, então descobri isso, você pode importa desta forma...

Links para estudo, [MDN - import](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

**Obs**: esta técnica esta bem abaixo na pg. da MDN. Bom estudo!

```js
const

// ARMAZENARA AS FUNCOES/METODOS CARREGADOS
MODULOS = {},

fc_import_m = async function (arg = false) {

  // CONDICAO CHECO VALOR DO ARG RECEBIDO
  if (!arg)

    // FUNCAO return FINALIZA PROCESSO
    return;

  // FUNCAO IMPORT MODULOS
  await import((typeof arg === 'object' && arg.hasOwnProperty ('a') ? arg.a : arg)).then((argM) => {
  // FUNCAO .then PARA RETORNO DA PROMESSA

    // LOOP PARA LISTAGEM E ARMAZENAMENTO
    for (let argV in argM) {

      // CONDICAO CHECA SE O ARMAZENAMENTO DEVE SER A PARTIR DE UMA NOVA PROP. PAI PARA VARIADOS METODOS DO MODULO
      if (typeof arg === 'object' && arg.hasOwnProperty ('m')) {

        // CONDICAO CHECA SE A PROP. JA EXISTE
        if (!MODULOS.hasOwnProperty (arg.m))

          /*
          SETO OBJ

          MODULOS[(arg.m]: obj, propriedades e valores armazenados do mudulo recebido
          */
          MODULOS[arg.m] = {};

        /*
        SETO OBJ

        MODULOS[(arg.m][argV]: obj, propriedades e valores armazenados do mudulo recebido
        */
        MODULOS[arg.m][argV] = argM[argV];

      } else {

        /*
        SETO OBJ

        MODULOS[(argV]: obj, propriedades e valores armazenados do mudulo recebido
        */
        MODULOS[argV] = argM[argV];

      }

    }

  }).catch ((argE) => {
  // FUNCAO .catch PARA RETORNO COM FALHA DA PROMESSA

    // FUNCAO throw ENVIA UM TypeError NOTIFICANDO
    throw new TypeError(`! error: contate suporte caso continue ${argE}`);

    // FUNCAO return FINALIZA PROCESSO
    return;

  });

};


/*
NomeModulo, opcional, remover caso queira que o nome da funcao no modulo seja setada
*/
fc_import_m ({m: 'NomeDoModulo', a: './modulo.js'});

fc_import_m ('./modulo.js');
```

Comment: So uma obs: se tiver quaisquer error na sintaxe do modulo a ser carregado ele cairá no `catch`.

Comment: Oi, obrigado pela sua sapiência e boa vontade, você tem alguma referência de estudo sobre escopos, e também poderia me dizer se, usando babel/webpack isso ajuda a globalizar(sic) meus códigos e lidar melhor com esse cenário?

Comment: @EliseuB. então, isso e bem complexo, eu não sei como e a estrutura de seu sistema mas tente utilizar um contexto raiz/pai, você já está utilizando a técnica IIFE isso é importante, assim você vai poder evitar que seus módulos e métodos importados fiquem expostos globalmente, ai você faz algo dinâmico, utilizar o `import` desta forma e muito poderoso, você ainda utiliza o jQuery que e uma mão na roda, amo muito! Na questão de contexto/escopos e estudos, sempre uso Google, MDN w W3Schools, mas MDN tem me ajudado muito, de um tempo para cá o Stackoverflow também...

Comment: continuando, a grande chave/segredo e o conjunto que você utiliza, sua estrutura, o esqueleto do seu sistema. A anos venho trabalhando em um sistema, após uns 3 anos repetindo muitos arquivos index.js vi que podia carregar o mundo com apenas uma chamada `ajax` e um index.js... hahaha, é trabalhoso mas valeu a pena. Veja a estrutura como você pode alinhar para reutilizar os métodos, faça um contexto privado. Isso tudo a grosso modo como falei, é complexo, solucione os seus problemas com scripts simples sempre, depois foque em segurança, desempenho e inteligencia/simplicidade... tempo rei! =D

Comment: Na questão do babel/webpack nunca utilizei, não posso lhe dizer, por nada, fico feliz em ajudar!